Why ,marriage 'guidance" but 'marriage ,certificate", 'marriage ,counselling, etc.?
In the Longman Pronunciation Dictionary, Professor John Wells writes that English compounds often take early stress, but the phrase "marriage guidance" is marked in this dictionary as "ˌmarriage 'guidance", making it an exception to this rule.
What intrigues me here is that other compounds start with "marriage" take the early stress pattern, such as "marriage license", "marriage certificate", "marriage counselling", etc.
Then I also found another compound ends in "guidance" that is "career guidance" which also takes early stress pattern.
I'm still not being able to figure out any reasonable argument for why this happens. Could someone please help to explain?

"English compounds often take early stress"—I assume this means, "In a phrase that combines two words of multiple syllables each, the overall stress is often in the first word." I'm skeptical. Trying to think of examples, I keep finding that this is true only when the intent is to contrast the first word with a different one. E.g. "I work in marine biology"—the emphasis is either equal, or in "biology." But "I work in both cell biology and marine biology"—now the emphasis is in "marine."

I wouldn't stress 'marriage guidance' in a different way from your other phrases. Who says it should be?

Where the stress goes in a compound is often dependent on the context. As someone learning English this is a fairly abstruse thing to be focussing on.

There's an obvious reason why the OP might have heard marriage guidance delivered with different stress to marriage license and marriage certificate, and it's right there in his final alternative - marriage counseling. That simply serves to remind us that people usually go TO a marriage guidance counselor, not FOR marriage guidance. The 3 most common words after marriage guidance are all versions of counselor.

(There's no particular words that immediately follow marriage license or marriage certificate, because they're both ordinary 2-word nouns that don't usually need anything else.)

...so "early stress" just means we're more likely to deliver it as marriage 'guidance counselor rather than marriage guidance 'counselor, which makes sense to me.

@KateBunting: The transcription "ˌmarriage 'guidance" appears in the Longman Pronunciation Dictionary. The Oxford English dictionary also gives it as the UK pronunciation, and the Cambridge Dictionary website for both the UK and US pronunciations.

It doesn't necessarily have to be pronounced with this stress pattern.
I'm American, and my first reaction to your question was that I would place primary stress on the first syllable of marriage guidance, just like I would for marriage certificate, etc. The Oxford English Dictionary lists /ˈmɛrɪdʒ ˌɡaɪdns/ for the U.S. pronunciation, vs. /ˌmarɪdʒ ˈɡʌɪdns/ for the U.K.
That said, after thinking it over more, I realized that "marriage guidance" may not be a phrase I use that often, as it seems to be more of a UK term. The Cambridge Dictionary website describes "marriage counseling" as the US equivalent. So how I would pronounce it might not count for much.
I also searched for examples of the phrase in context and noticed that it often occurs in longer phrases such as "National Marriage Guidance Council" or "marriage guidance counsellor": stress on the first syllable of "guidance" sounds less odd to me in the context of phrases like that than when I think of the phrase in isolation.
To me, it seems possible that "career guidance" could have the same variability in its stress pattern. I think I could hear some later-stressed pronunciations of it on Youglish.

It's the familiar noun phrase marriage 'guidance counsellor/counselling that nails this one.

@sumelic, it's interesting to see that Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary shows a different stress pattern from Oxford English Dictionary for this compound:

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/marriage-guidance?q=marriage+guidance
https://www.oed.com/dictionary/marriage-guidance_n

